# pandemic - can a city outbreak more than once per infect city turn?

Tags: pandemic

Scenario:
- infection rate is 2
- Tehran currently has 2 cubes, Baghdad has 3 cubes

1. At end of turn, first infect card drawn is Baghdad. It outbreaks and adds a cube to Tehran so Tehran now has 3 cubes.
2. Second card drawn is Tehran, which outbreaks.

Question: Does the Tehran outbreak cause a chain reaction outbreak in Baghdad? Or is Baghdad skipped because it already had an outbreak on this infect cities stage?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the second card will cause a chain reaction.

In a case like this you would have three total outbreaks happen. First one from the first card drawn, Baghdad. Then two more from the second card drawn, Tehran.

> **INFECTION:**
>   Infections
>   Flip over as many Infection cards from the top of the Infection Deck as the
>   current infection rate. This number is below the space of the Infection Rate
>   Track that has the infection rate marker. Flip these cards over one at a time,
>   infecting the city named on each card.
>
> To infect a city, place 1 disease cube matching its color onto the city, unless
>   this disease has been eradicated. If the city already has 3 cubes of this color,
>   do not place a 4th cube. Instead, an outbreak of this disease occurs in the city
>   (see Outbreaks below). Discard this card to the Infection Discard Pile.
>
> **OUTBREAKS:**
>   When a disease outbreak occurs, move the outbreaks marker forward
>   1 space on the Outbreaks Track. Then, place 1 cube of the disease color
>   on every city connected to the city. If any of them already has 3 cubes of
>   the disease color, do not place a 4th cube in those cities. Instead, in each of
>   them, a chain reaction outbreak occurs after the current outbreak is done.
>
> When a chain reaction outbreak occurs, first move the outbreaks marker
>   forward 1 space. Then, place cubes as above, except do not add a cube to
>   cities that have already had an outbreak (or a chain reaction outbreak) as
>   part of resolving the current Infection card.
>
> As a result of outbreaks, a city may have disease cubes of multiple colors on
>   it; up to 3 cubes of each color. This does not affect infections.

If you read the outbreaks section closely it only talks about not adding cubes to cities that have already had an outbreak for the current infection card only. So for the situation that you are dealing with there will be an outbreak for each infection card.

Comment: I dont think the op was asking if tehran would outbreak, he asked if baghdad would outbreak twice. I believe the amswer is yes. One for the first card then two for the second card. When drawing the second card baghdad has not yet had an outbreak for that card so it is not skipped. What is important is that tehran cant outbreak again after the outbreak chains to baghdad.

Comment: @Matt The way I read it is he is asking about Baghdad having an outbreak from the second card that is drawn which causes a cube to be added to it. But I have provided the rules which should help some.

Comment: okay, but you seem to suggest that baghdad does not outbreak when the tehran card is drawn, but it does.

Comment: @Matt Other then starting out with the statement that you would have two outbreaks happen? One from the first card and one from the second? While the outbreak counter does not advance all other actions from an outbreak do happen as stated in the rules I posted for a chain outbreak.

Comment: Oh, I see. By "you would have two outbreaks happen" you mean "you would have two outbreaks happen in baghdad." See, when I read "in this case you would have two outbreaks" I interpreted that to mean, "in the example given by the op there is a total of two outbreaks".

Comment: @Matt I agree. I think it just needs to be edited for clarity. There will be 3 outbreaks; 2 in Baghdad.

Comment: Thanks. And to confirm, the outbreak counter is incremented 3 times? (i.e. the chain reaction outbreak in Baghdad still increments the outbreak counter)

Comment: @PatrickFinnigan No, the outbreak counter will only move once per infection card even if multiple outbreaks occur, This is done to prevent you from losing after a bad infection card causes a large chain reaction.

Comment: There may be a better wording than the one I thought of, but the current wording is flat-out incorrect. It says that there will only be 2 outbreaks, when in fact there will be 3. I've edited to a new wording. If it's unclear, or anyone can think of a better wording, I'm all for it. But it definitely should not say "there will be 2 outbreaks."

Comment: @JoeW i believe you are mistaken about the outbreak counter. Chain reaction outbreaks do in fact increment the counter. The rules text you quoted specifically says so.

Comment: "When a chain reaction outbreak occurs, first move the outbreaks marker forward 1 space"

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, it appears that the order in which the cards are played is important. i.e., if Tehran is drawn first, it gets a third cube. Then when Baghdad is drawn, it outbreaks and so does Tehran. Only two outbreaks when the cards are played in this sequence.

Comment: This does not add anything new and it looks like it should be a comment rather then an answer.

Answer (score -4):

From what the rules state no city can outbreak more than once per infection cycle. Otherwise you would have outbreaks going back and forth in a never ending loop. So per your example. Baghdad would outbreak because it has 3 cubes causing Tehran to get a 3rd. Then Tehran would outbreak with the draw. Now as I play it Baghdad would not outbreak because you are still in the same infection cycle. From the other answer he makes it sound as if each card is its own infection cycle. So don't know for sure, but I have never played it as each card is its own cycle.

Comment: Where do you see "no city can outbreak more than once per infection cycle"? The wording I see is "Note that each city may only outbreak once in each chain reaction." This makes it clear that the limitation only applies to a single card draw, not to the whole phase/turn.